# Remove Decimal in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataset at column 'Time Period', I have series which contains 2018 and 2019.

When I plot it with 'countries and areas' column, I am getting results like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Fnr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDfYH.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is the `dtype` of the Time Period column ? `df.info()` will tell you the dtype and point out null values, as mentioned in Alexander Volkovsky's answer

If it is not `int` then enforcing it to integer should help :

```
df["Time Period"] = df["Time Period"].apply(int)
```

Edit: indeed, as pointed out by Alexander Volkovsky, astype(int) is the better way, but you still have to assign the result back :

```
df["Time Period"] = df["Time Period"].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `nan` value in this column. You must remove them first, then convert to int: `df["Time Period"].astype(int)`. Or you can try a new [nullable integer type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).